# How to get dropdown (and multiple) select value for a product collection?

Tags: product-attribute, magento-1.5, product-collection, dropdown-attribute

In Magento 1.5 on the product page, I created a product collection (for related products) like this (I've omitted filters):

```
// $_products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection') // this variation makes no difference.
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('some_text_attribute')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('some_dropdown_attr'); // does not work for dropdown/multiselect apparently
```

Now if I `echo $_products->getSelect()` I see that adding the dropdown attribute did nothing to modify the select. So the data for 'some_dropdown_attr' is not available that way. Isn't there a way to add it to the select. And if not, there certainly must be a way to get the value(s) of any dropdown (or multiselect) attribute for a certain product.

```
$_text_attr[] = array();
$_dropdown_attr[] = array();
foreach($_products as $_product) {
  $_text_attr[] = $_product->getData('some_text_attribute');
  // 1.) get resource - doesn't work
  // $_dropdown_attr[] = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('some_dropdown_attr')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); // results in array of "No"
  // 2.) get attribute text - doesn't work
  // $_dropdown_attr[] = $_product->getAttributeText('some_dropdown_attr'); // results in array of NULLS. 
  // Get attributes - doesn't work - array of "No". Also, even if it did work it seems idiotic to have to get all product attributes just to get the value of one
  // $_attrs = $_product->getAttributes();
  // $_dropdown_attr[] = $_attrs['some_dropdown_attr']->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the product you are using for tests has the attribute 'some_dropdown_attr'?

Comment: @Marius Are you suggesting that one of the methods I tried should have worked? The value was visible in the Admin view for the product. I confirmed it was the right attribute by looking at the form field's `id` using Chrome's "Inspect Element." The id = the attribute code.

Comment: In my opinion this should work `$_product->getAttributeText('some_dropdown_attr')`

Answer (score 2):

As @marius points out in the comments the following should work:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('some_dropdown_attr');
```

Therefore only the following could be happening:

- You must have mis-named your dropdown attribute
- Ensure that the attribute has valid values applied on the current store view

If all else fails, there may be a problem with your attribute setup code; for instance, not visible in the frontend isn't set properly and you're using flat tables...

In that case to debug output it with the following code:

```
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('some_dropdown_attr')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

If that works check your catalog attribute configuration or disable flat indexes.

Comment: Is there a way to go around the flat table and use the eav tables as the data source even when flat tables are activated? When I have tried your suggestions, I will let you know if they have worked.

Comment: Your `getResource()` code to get the value of the attribute is returning "No", even though that is not the value of the attribute for that product. In the backend, I can see it using chrome's inspect element: `<label for="some_dropdown_attr">Some Dropdown</label>` and its value is NOT "No". Any ideas?